# Cannot set property in an object in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.objectData = {};
$scope.objectData[key]["digits"] =  set.first+','+set.second+','+set.third+','+set.fourth;
```

here key is a numerical value.The error is

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'digits' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of `$scope.objectData[key]` to an object before you can add more keys to it.

```
$scope.objectData[key] = {};
$scope.objectData[key]['digits'] = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to initalize the object `$scope.objectData[key]` so the right code would be:

```
$scope.objectData = {};
$scope.objectData[key] = {};
$scope.objectData[key]["digits"] = set.first+','+set.second+','+set.third+','+set.fourth;
```